# Small luxury hotels in Sardinia near beach

Tags: beaches, luxury, sardinia

I'm looking for recommendations for small luxury hotels in Sardinia near a nice beach for a short break in April. Nice walks and a nearby small town with interesting things whether historic or just shops and restaurants would be a nice bonus but hotel and beach are top priority. it's a special treat so can splash out a bit. That's it really!
Thanks
Mark